# Twitter bootstrap 3 - layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to define a layout like this:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    |              |                                        |
    |              |                                        |
    |              |               content <div>            |
    |              |                                        |
    |              |                                        |
    |    sidebar   |                                        |
    |     <div>    |                                        |
    |              | ---------------------------------------|
    |              |                                        |
    |              |           input box   <input>          |
    |              |                                        |
    ---------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not a frontend guy at all, so please help me with this layout using bootstrap 3. I have been pulling my hairs for floating, positioning, etc.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-md-9 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 600px;
}

.content {
    height: 550px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.input-box {
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}

.input-box input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

As you can see, I hardcoded the heights, I want to make it extend to the full height as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the HTML and CSS that you have created so far, otherwise this question risks being closed.

Comment: Sorry guys, just posted my html and css.

Comment: http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started/#examples

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sidebar (with toggle) layout using bootstrap 3.

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/navigation-sidebar-with-toggle

If you prefer the sidebar with no toggle, just ignore the #menu-toggle JS.